# How to build XYZ layer source for custom scales?

Tags: openlayers

I have tile images in scales: 4, 6, 8, 12, 14 (in subdirectories). In smaller scale tiles are in higher zoom (in 14 scale zoom is minimal, in 4 scale zoom is maximal). I have prameters as below for this map like projection, width of all area (extent) in pixels etc. How to define correct `ol.source.XYZ` object with `tileGrid` and `tileUrlFunction` for this ?

Partially working example (works for scale 4 and 8, not for other):

```
var origin = [101235.72703025967, 781405.7611248483];

// counted from parameters
var resolutions = [
    10160.181718152791,
    5080.090859076396,
    2540.045429538198,
    1270.022714769099,
    635.0113573845495,
    317.5056786922747,
    158.75283934613736
];

var source = new ol.source.XYZ({
    projection: 'EPSG:2180',
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
        origin: origin, // left upper corner
        resolutions: resolutions,
        tileSize: [256, 256]
    }),
    tileUrlFunction: function(coord){
        var zoom = coord[0];
        var x = coord[1];
        var y = -coord[2]-1;

        // how to convert zoom to scale (directory) ?
        // ...
        // i have something like below, that works for 4 and 8 scales
        // but need to work with other scales
        var scale = Math.pow(2, maxScale - zoom);

        return baseUrl+'/'+scale+'/'+(y<0?'n':'')+Math.abs(y)+'_'+(x<0?'n':'')+Math.abs(x)+".png";
    }
});
```

Parameters:

```
    tile_size   = (256, 256),
    scales      = [4, 6, 8, 12, 14],
    size        = (20983, 16417),

    origin      = (101235.727030259673484,781405.761124848271720),
    pixel_size  = (39.688209847118202,-39.686773552345521),

    upper_left  = (101235.727,  781405.761),
    lower_left  = (101235.727,  129868.000),
    upper_right = (934013.434,  781405.761),
    lower_right = (934013.434,  129868.000),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify only the resolutions for levels 4, 6, 8, 12, 14 in the tilegrid resolutions array you could get the correct z for the url using

```
var z = [4, 6, 8, 12, 14][coord[0]];
```

Comment: Do You mean that resolutions hasn't to be divisible one by next one with result equals 2 ( 2 * 2540.045429538198 = 5080.090859076396; 2 * 5080.090859076396 = 10160.181718152791, etc) ?

Comment: some services have resolutions such as 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, ...

Comment: I had to change order of scales array to `var z = [14, 12, 8, 6, 4][coord[0]];` and it worked. Thank You a lot.